# Can I authenticate users through the original login screen with Graph API and Azure ADB2C?

Tags: azure, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I would like to create an authentication function.
And I want to manage the user information in ADB2C.
ADB2C has a user flow, but I prefer to use my own original login screen that I created myself.
For this reason, we believe that we need to use Graph　API and MSAL.
Is it possible to perform authentication in this configuration?

Original Login Screen(NOT Userflow in Azure ADB2C) ⇔ Graph API ⇔ Azure ADB2C
↑This is the architecture I have in mind.
I'm a first-timer, please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend NOT to use your own form but to **customize** the Azure AD B2C user interface (See [Customize the user interface with HTML templates in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)).

If you're dead set on using your own form, you have to [set up a resource owner password credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-custom-policy&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203). However, due to security concerns, this approach should only be utilized for legacy solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There are no Graph API calls for authentication.

You have to use the B2C screen.

However, you can [embed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-user-flow) your screen.

"For a simpler sign-up or sign-in experience, you can avoid redirecting users to a separate sign-up or sign-in page, or generating a pop-up window. By using the inline frame  HTML element, you can embed the Azure AD B2C sign-in user interface directly into your web application".